# Flutter/Dart: return not waiting "toList" with async function to finish

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, sqflite

I'm working on an API sync using Flutter and SQFLite.

I get the data from the API, map it, and then add to SQL item by item:

```
    return (response as List).map((tmp) {
      print('• API: apiSync - Inserting News');
      DBProvider.db.updateNews(ArtNews.fromJson(tmp));
    }).toList();
```

Everything works fine, but there is a small problem: the return is called before the 'updateNews' is done.

updateNews is a simple async function that writes data on SQFLite.

This creates a big issue: the app opens before the sync is over and data is still being written on DB.

I've tried using AWAIT, but it doesn't make any effect:

```
   (response as List).map((tmp) async{
      print('• API: apiSync - Inserting $type');
      await DBProvider.db.updateNews(ArtNews.fromJson(tmp));
    }).toList();
    return 'done';
```

updateNews is called dozens of times, the toList ends, returns 'done', but the updateNews is still adding content to the DB.

I guess there is something I'm missing on toList or async. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
await Future.wait((response as List).map((tmp) {
      print('• API: apiSync - Inserting $type');
      return DBProvider.db.updateNews(ArtNews.fromJson(tmp));
    }));
return 'done';
```

Gist for reference:

https://dartpad.dev/?id=e72b1dc9013e2add447a90979bed7aab

Comment: Future.wait did the trick! It's only missing async and await on your answer. I'll edit so it can help if someone else has the same issue. :)

Comment: It doesn't need the async and await.

Comment: Without await and async it doesn't wait the updateNews to finish. Tested. Sorry for the edit, feel free to revert. If anyone else comes by with this issue, give it a try with async and await. Will keep it as accepted as it helped me to fix the issue, thanks!

Comment: No what was missing was the return statement, sorry about that. The return was added. The idea with Future.wait() is to have a list of Futures that is awaited, and when the last is finished, then all is well. I added a dartpad example demonstrating it. Meaning, when you remove the print() when you map the list, you can write the method as an expression body with => notation as the dartpad example does..